# The order of a Cisco routing table

Tags: networking

I was wondering if there is a certain order to a routing table that a router uses when loading entries? Does it go by the lowest AD and that is fop of the table, does the destination network's IP address matter, etc? Or is the order randomly generated as routes are learned?

Comment: What do you mean when loading entries? Are you talking about when it's actually trying to forward a route? Or are you simply talking about the output of `show ip route`?

Answer (score 0):

When Cisco router printing entries from routing table after show ip route it starts from numerically lowest ip address so for example if you have routes to 90.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 140.10.0.0/16 networks then your routing table will looks like this

10.0.0.0/8

90.0.0.0/8

140.10.0.0/16